# Not able to use projectile-mode after installation from Emacs package manager

Tags: projectile

I am trying to install the `projectile` library. I am using Emacs 24.4.1, and I installed  `projectile-20150405.126` from the Emacs package manager. Then I tried to activate it in my init file:

```
(require 'projectile)
(projectile-global-mode)
```

But this gives an error when I am starting Emacs:

- Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/hakon/.emacs':
  File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, projectile

I tried to debug using `emacs -Q` and it seems like I am missing a package called `dash`..

According to the installation instructions at http://batsov.com/projectile/ I should not need to install `dash` first when using the package manager..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Emacs initializes packages *after* loading your init file, for historic and obscure reasons.  Hence packages are normally not available in your init file.

You need explicitly initialize the package manager first with `(package-initialize)`. This adds all packages to `load-path`, thus fixing this specific error.  Alternatively, you can delay Projectile setup until after `init.el` was loaded, by using `(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'projectile-global-mode)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was confused when the manual said `You can enable Projectile globally like this (projectile-global-mode)`.. I thought this meant I should put that line in the init file.. Maybe it should instead say: `You can enable Projectile globally like this (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'projectile-global-mode)` ?